# Can I parse stdin and stdout into char* and then give them pointers?

Tags: c, linux

Say i have these pointers:

```
 char* stin, stout;
```

If i do something like:

```
 stin = (char*)stdin;
 stout = (char*)stdout;
```

will those two pointers ALWAYS return whatever is in standard in and standard out? Or will I get some kind of error. so, if I do something like

```
fprint("Stdin contains %s:\n", *stin);
```

will this return garbage?

Answer (score 0):

> will this return garbage?

It might. `stdin` and `stdout` are of the type `FILE*`. Trying to treat them as a `char *`  and printing it as a string makes no sense, and there is no guarantees as to what will happen or won't happen - the behavior is undefined.

A FILE* is meant to be operated upon by standard C functions such as fread(), fputs() and similar.

Another undefined behavior is the printf statement itself.

```
 fprint("Stdin contains %s:\n", *stin);
                        ^^      ^^^
```

By using `%s` you are promising that the argument is a string, that is a  `char *` which is a sequence of characters ending with a nul byte. bit `*stin` is not a pointer (a `char*`), it's a `char`, so the types doesn't match.

Comment: I understand. I'm trying to work with pipes that execute several commands.. like ls | sort.. so ls' output into sort.. i know i can manipulate pipes into doing what i want but i was wondering if i could have the stdout of ls have a pointer and send it to the stdin of sort. Thanks for clearing that up though.